# Using RecycleView in fragment Val cannot be reassigned problem

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i tried to use recycleview in fragment but i get "val cannot be reassigned" error.I am confused because i didnt give any value, ı used variable.
my mainacitvity:

```
class KategoriFragment : Fragment() {
    var araclarKategori = ArrayList<AracMarka>()

    private lateinit var galleryViewModel: GalleryViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        galleryViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel::class.java)
        var root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false)
        rvarackategori = root.findViewById(R.id.rvarackategori) as RecyclerView
        var MyAdapter = AracMarkaAdapter(araclarKategori)
        rvarackategori.adapter = MyAdapter
        veriKaynaginiDoldur()
        return root
    }

    fun veriKaynaginiDoldur(): ArrayList<AracMarka> {

        var aracLogo = arrayOf(R.drawable.opellogo, R.drawable.chevroletlogo)
        var aracismi = resources.getStringArray(R.array.arabaisim)

        for (i in 0..araclarKategori.size - 1) {

            var eklenecekaracKategori = AracMarka(aracismi[i], aracLogo[i])
            araclarKategori.add(eklenecekaracKategori)
        }
        return araclarKategori

    }
}
```

This is my adapter:

```
    class AracMarkaAdapter(tumKategori: ArrayList<AracMarka>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<AracMarkaAdapter.AracMarkaViewHolder>() {

        var araclar = tumKategori

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AracMarkaViewHolder {

            var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            var arackategori = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arac_kategori, parent, false)

            return AracMarkaViewHolder(arackategori)

        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return araclar.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AracMarkaViewHolder, position: Int) {

            holder.aracismi.text=araclar.get(position).aracAdi
            holder.aracLogo.setImageResource(araclar.get(position).aracLogo)

        }   

        class AracMarkaViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

            var teksatirKategori= itemView
            var aracismi= teksatirKategori.tvaracAdi
            var aracLogo=teksatirKategori.img_arac_sembol
}
    }
```

Comment: `val` is immutable/read only. You cannot assign a value to it. Use `var` instead

Comment: Can you post your error log?

Comment: ı have not assing val. I used var. log sad   Val cannot be reassigned for rvarackategori = root.findViewById(R.id.rvarackategori) as RecyclerView

Comment: ok.. it seems you have re-assinged a synthetic-id  just add val before  rvarackategori and please refer to this blog https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/

Comment: Where is rvarackategori defined? It isn't in your code

Comment: @ScottCooper rvarackategori is my recycleview name.Its defined my fragment layout.

Comment: @nik I added val it works. But now, ı havent see my recycleview in my fragment. It is empty.

Comment: it may because of you haven't added LayoutManager to recyclerview

Comment: Please post your layout xml file

Answer (score 1):

```
rvarackategori = root.findViewById(R.id.rvarackategori) as RecyclerView
```

That line is your problem. You've set the RecyclerView id to be `@id/rvarackategori`, when you create a Fragment in Kotlin you can access views in the layout without using `findViewById`, you just need to use the id of the view.

So in this case you're accessing `rvarackategori` by its id, then you are finding the same view using findViewById and trying to assign it to itself.

Try this:

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        galleryViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel::class.java)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        var MyAdapter = AracMarkaAdapter(araclarKategori)
        rvarackategori.adapter = MyAdapter
        veriKaynaginiDoldur()
    }
```

Comment: agreed...also need to add layout manager either in xml or in code

Comment: i cannot add xml file. ıt says: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: It's ok I don't need to see it, I can see the problem from the line I posted above.

Comment: @ScottCooper Hello Scott,  ı added onViewCreated function as you mentioned it.Now my onCreateView is empty. I guess ı shouldl layout manager also.Is it should be in onViewcreated  function also? Because fragment is empty now.

Comment: onCreateView is called for you to provide your layout file so it shouldn't be empty.

onViewCreated is called when your view has been created and the widgets have been instantiated. You should add your layout manager in this function.